# Entity framework using vb.net,stored proc and involve multiple tables

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, join, frameworks, entity

I have a person table with first name,last name, phoneid other details.
The phoneid is an identity column in Phonetable.
I need to add/update the person info. 
First, it should check if the phone number entered already exists in PhoneNumber table. If so, get the PhoneID from this table and save it to Persons table's PhoneID column.
If the phone number does not exist, insert the phone number to PhoneNumber table and return the phoneID and update the Persons table.

I need to do this using Entity Framework and VB.NET.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If no duplicates on phone numbers are expected why do you need a relation table for these? If they do then this is fine. The purpose for relational tables is to not duplicate data - in this case I might throw the I don't care card in place of simplicity.

This gets an `IEnumerable(Of PhoneNumber)` which should yield only one result.

```
Private Function CheckPhoneNumber(phNumber As String) As Integer
  Dim query = PhoneNumbers.Where(Function(o) o.Number = phNumber)
   'if query is empty it does not exist
  If query IsNot Nothing Then
    Return query.FirstOrDefault.PhoneId
  Else
   'make new record in this table
  End If
End Function
```